# How does Sugar Rush understand outside weapons?

Tags: plot-explanation, wreck-it-ralph

In the movie [Wreck-It Ralph](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1772341/), how can the Sugar Rush game understand outside weapons and the way they function if they weren't originally part of the game?

For example, in Sugar Rush(a kart racing game), Sergeant Calhoun uses her weapons, but how does the Sugar Rush game world understand the weapons function if it wasn't originally in the game code to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because characters from different games can and do significantly interact with each other routinely.**

This is so common that there is Game Central Station – a place where characters quickly “commute” between games.

They have inter-game therapy sessions with each other:

We also see the ability of game characters to change *the original game code* of a game.

Game characters can permanently move to another game: Turbo/King Candy did so when he left his original game to take up residence in Sugar Rush.

On the whole, *Wreck-It Ralph* is a world where almost anything is possible with games.